# Chunk a collection and loop/assign each chunk a param from another array

Tags: php, laravel

How would one tackle this need?:

I have user `$phone_numbers` => 200000

`$api_sending_numbers` (can send 36000 text messages an hour to a phone number)

How would one divide the `$phone_numbers` and assign a `$sending_number`?

My attempt is using `chunk()`

```
$phone_numbers = PhoneNumber::get();

foreach ($phone_numbers->chunk(5) as $chunk_phone_numbers) {

foreach ($chunk_phone_numbers as $user) {
    echo $user->phone_number;

}
};
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your attempt?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). You also don't really need to chunk, unless you're trying to save memory.

Comment: yes the idea is to queue each chunk as a job with time intervals , assign a sending_number to each chunk  and to save memory. and reassign a sending_number for any additional chunks in a serialized order.